# Rank of matrices product with one invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given $A \in\mathbb{R^{7\times8}}$, $B \in\mathbb{R^{8\times8}}$, $C \in\mathbb{R^{8\times7}}$ and provided that **B is invertible**, how can one check whether $$rank(AC) = rank(ABC)$$ is true?

$B$ is invertible and $n\times n$, so it is linearly equivalent to $I_n$, but I am not sure if this is what we need from the fact that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: I guess, this is *not true* in general. Try to achieve $AC=0$ while $ABC\ne 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\pmatrix{1&2\cr}\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}\pmatrix{1\cr-2\cr}=0$$

$$\pmatrix{1&2\cr}\pmatrix{1\cr-2\cr}\ne0$$

Comment: So, it is generally not true. (I guess the same applies for bigger dimensions too). But how can I generally prove this?

Comment: By generalizing this example.

Comment: Can you explain this please? I see that rank(AC) != rank(ABC), but I am not sure that I understand how to prove it. The fact that B is invertible is only given to "guide" the search for a counter-example?

Thanks you.

Comment: For a general counterexample, based on this answer, just use $(1,\ 2)$ as $A$ and fill in its other entries with $0$. Similarly for $C$, and let $B$ be the identity matrix with its first two columns exchanged.

Comment: Thanks @Berci I see how it works, but it is not obvious to me how I could have picked the specific arrays. Is there another way to prove that rank(AC) != rank(ABC) without counter example? Thanks

Comment: Whether the two ranks are equal depends on the specific choices you make for $A$, $B$, and $C$. There's no way to prove that the ranks are never equal (since that's false), so the natural thing to do is to find specific examples where the ranks are not equal.